# $_FILES always empty when upload file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple image in codeigniter. but when i `print_r($_FILES)` it always return empty array. alse return `undefined index : userfile`.

**php.ini**

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

**View Code :**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/test', array('id' => 'add-listing'));?>
  <h3>Photo</h3>
  <section>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select photos</label>
      <input type="file" id="files" class="form-control required" name="userfile[]" multiple/>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="photos"></div> //this one for image viewer
  </section>
</form>
```

[EDITED]

PHP Code :

```
function test(){
    print_r($_FILES['userfile']);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it's work's for me..So please show full source code.

Comment: any idea what i miss ? @NikhilVaghla

Comment: @IbnuHabibie add your PHP code

Comment: that's all my code . in admin/test controller i just do print_r($_FILES['userfile']); it return error undefined index : userfile

Comment: @IbnuHabibie Just use `print_r($_FILES);` and check

Comment: it's empty  Array() @Spartan.

Comment: @IbnuHabibie Check this https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/

Comment: i've tried with single image in different function . i used $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') and it's working. but if i tried to get value of $_FILES it always return null or undefined index